# lookup for custom object is not working lightning web component

Tags: lightning-web-components

May be its very easy question  for you guys  but I am stuck badly.when I put  `object-api-name="Contact"`  and `field-name="AccountId"`  then its working but for custom object as mention below is not  working

```
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Coaching_Template_Sections__c" >
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Coaching_Sections__c " variant="label-hidden" >
      </lightning-input-field> 
  </lightning-record-edit-form>
```

when I put  `object-api-name="Contact"`  and `field-name="AccountId"`  then its working but for custom object as mention above  is not  working

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by not working?

Comment: mean  input field does not show on  screeen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please notice that you have extra space in field definition**

[image]

Comment: its workesd  but  its  only show recent select record. How to show all record of lookup